# Не могу получить популярные аудиозаписи VK

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, аудио

получаю токен юзера и сразу пытаюсь получить

```
VKRequest audios = VKApi.audio().getPopular();
```

И получаю `error 15` :( Читал, что сторонние разработчики не могут работать с аудио но как же тогда работает [это](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.novateh.hardon?)

Что я не так делаю? И вообще почему для получения популярных аудиозаписей нужен токен? Мне их надо получать даже если пользователь не залогинился.

Comment: «все приложения в GP» это какие например?

Comment: @andreymal, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.novateh.hardon ну одно только)) по крайней мере только его я проверял

Comment: Они же отключили публичное АПИ для аудио. В конце прошлого года. ВОт линк - https://vk.com/dev/audio_api

Comment: @Moonvvell автор в вопросе пишет, что он в курсе, и приводит в пример приложение, которое каким-то чудом работает несмотря на это

Comment: Расковырял это приложение: оно прикидывается официальным Android-клиентом и потому работает, но вообще по идее такое запрещено

Comment: По ссылке что я привел, внизу написано что можно связатся с техподдержкой ВК и если у тебя мега крутое приложение то, теоретически, дадут доступ к аудио апи.

Comment: @andreymal тоже декомпилировал но не нашел ничего, как вы поняли, что оно им прикидывается?

Comment: @Flippy погрепал айдишники официальных клиентов, в одном из классов устанавливается «client_id = 0x22b2d3» (или 2274003 в десятичной системе счисления), а это как раз идентификатор официального Android-клиента

Comment: @andreymal, если подсунуть оф id то я получаю security error 5 issue какой то, нашел com.vk.sdk.appId в том приложении написал себе и получаю ответ типа музыка в оф клиенте как получить музыку?

Comment: Не разбираюсь в Android, но думаю, можно посмотреть не только id, но и какие конкретно запросы делаются в приложении. Другой вариант — авторизоваться ВК и отправлять запросы на https://vk.com/al_audio.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PROFIT!**

Я это сделал! Декомпилировал одно приложение и узнал какой сейчас используется хак.

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/kateWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
public class VkontakteWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
    {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        MainActivity.this.parseUrl(url);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView kateWV = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.kateWebView);
    kateWV.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    kateWV.clearCache(true);
    kateWV.setWebViewClient(new VkontakteWebViewClient());
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
    kateWV.loadUrl(Auth.getUrl("2685278", Auth.getSettings()));
}

public void parseUrl(String url){
    if (url != null) {
        try {
            if (url.startsWith(Auth.redirect_url)) {
                if (!url.contains("error=")) {
                    String[] auth = Auth.parseRedirectUrl(url);
                    saveTokenToSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext(), Auth.VK_SDK_ACCESS, "scope=groups,audio,offline&https_required=1&expires_in=0&access_token=" + auth[0] + "&user_id=" + Long.parseLong(auth[1]));
                }
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AudioActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public void saveTokenToSharedPreferences(Context ctx, String tokenKey, String code) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
    edit.putString(tokenKey, code);
    edit.apply();
}
}
```

**Auth.java**

```
public class Auth
{
public static final String VK_SDK_ACCESS = "VK_SDK_ACCESS_TOKEN_PLEASE_DONT_TOUCH";
public static String redirect_url;

static {
    redirect_url = "https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html";
}

public static String getUrl(String api_id, String settings) {
    return "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=" + api_id + "&display=mobile&scope=" + settings + "&redirect_uri=" + URLEncoder.encode(redirect_url) + "&response_type=token" + "&v=" + "5.53";
}

public static String getSettings() {
    return "notify,friends,photos,audio,video,docs,status,notes,pages,wall,groups,messages,offline,notifications";
}

public static String[] parseRedirectUrl(String url) throws Exception {
    String access_token = Utils.extractPattern(url, "access_token=(.*?)&");
    String user_id = Utils.extractPattern(url, "user_id=(\\d*)");
    if (user_id == null || user_id.length() == 0 || access_token == null || access_token.length() == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to parse redirect url " + url);
    }
    return new String[]{access_token, user_id};
}
}
```

В итоге после авторизации через `WebView`  в `preferences` будет сохранен токен

```
<string name="VK_SDK_ACCESS_TOKEN_PLEASE_DONT_TOUCH">scope=groups,audio,offline&amp;https_required=1&amp;expires_in=0&amp;access_token=тут_токен_юзера&amp;user_id=тут_id_юзера</string>
```

Далее можно работать с API VK. Лично у меня происходит переход в `AudioActivity`.

Примерный код

```
VKRequest request = VkApi.audio().getPopular();
request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response)
            {
          //выводим json с музыкой в логи
                Log.d("vkmusic", response.responseString);
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error){
                Log.d("err", error.toString());
            }
        });
request.start();
```

Ну и все, можно юзать.

**Результат**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас все аудиозаписи извлекаются таким образом? У меня, например, `audio.getById` -41489995_202246189  не работает, возвращает пустой ответ.

Comment: @Im ieee, хм. Не знаю даже

Answer (score 1):

И вот еще **класс Utils**

```
class Utils {
    public static String extractPattern(String string, String pattern) {
        Pattern searchPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher matcher = searchPattern.matcher(string);
        Log.d("pattern found - ", matcher.find() ? ("yes" + matcher.group(1)) : "no");
        return matcher.group(1);
    }
}
```