# Аудио API для ВК

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, взлом

В конце 2016 года ВК закрыл сторонним приложениям доступ к аудиозаписям через соответствующий API. Но в App Store по прежнему есть немало приложений, которые предоставляют аудиозаписи. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно взломать данный API.

Comment: Ваш вопрос наверное закроют, тк здесь не обсуждается вопросы взлома. То что в сторе предлагается, больше не работает. Я все конечно не попробовал, но многие.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637308/Не-могу-получить-популярные-аудиозаписи-vk

Answer (score 3):

Api бывает двух типов, публичное и "для избранных", например Kate Mobile.
Чтобы ваше приложение попало в список избранных, надо написать в тех. поддержку соответствующий запрос. Далее они там решают, давать вам расширенные возможности или нет. Это официальный путь, неофициальный по ссылке

Есть статья на эту тему.
[гайд по обходу](http://telegra.ph/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC-VK-API-12-31)

Comment: удивило, что telegra.ph работает по обычном http, а не https (учитывая, что это telegram, который помешан на безопасности).

Answer (score 1):

Официально, как сказал @sviat-volkov надо обращаться в поддержку VK. Из плюсов - предоставят в случае положительного решения полноценный доступ к методам Music API. Из минусов - туда нужно идти как минимум с чем-то готовым, к тому же Контакт не просто так закрыл свой раздел с музыкой.

Неофициально можно юзать Private API, т.е. API самого приложения VK. Из плюсов - обход минусов официального подхода. Из минусов - менее стабильная работа, более капризное в использовании (нужно соблюдать частоту запросов, заходить с "правильных" IP, чтобы не вывалилась капча). К тому же в этом случае вам никто не скажет о новых изменениях в Private API.

P.S. На отдельные лазейки не советую уповать, т.к. их периодически прикрывают. Если решили что-то писать по этой теме, идите сразу одним из указанных подходов, либо комбинируйте по вкусу)))